# view sliding over layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I have relative layout. Within which I have many views like edit text, text views and so on. I do lots of animations in that. Everything was perfectly fine. But at one point, I have a requirement.

It is the password page. Create and confirm password. Two edittexts one after another. If the password doesnt meet the requirement, a plain orange view should slide up with error message "Invalid password".

So I put create and confirm password in linear layout. The linear layout will slide up, letting user type in passwords. After validation, if there is an error, the linear layout should slide down and the plain view will slide up. I kept the view invisible and when required I made it visible and wrote the code to slide up. The same code works when I just use single edit text instead of linear layout. But it is not working when using linear layout. Am I doing something wrong?

Adding code to it. The code specific to this issue starts with  till the end of coding

I declared linear layout as view and NOT VIEWGROUP.

EDIT: After doing analysis, I found that the view I am trying to slide up after sliding down the layout is hidden somewhere in the view hierarchy.

view.bringToFront() helps to bring the error view to the front and slides up.

But after that the problem is, after my linear layout slide down, the error view is not sliding up straight away. Because I am using bringToFront(), it displays the view first on the whole screen (with background color as orange) and then the sliding starts.

I am not sure whether it is correct but I fixed this issue like this.

1. no background color has been given to the view
2. I used errorView.bringToFront () and errorView.setVisibility(true) in the animationEnd() of a Layout slidingdown animation listener.
3. I defined sliding up animation for the errorView in the same animationEnd() of layout sliding down listener
4. In the animationStart() of errorView sliding up animation listener, I defined the background color of the errorView. Now its working as expected.

But let me know better way of doing this.

//Declaration

View greyView, orangeView, yellowView, blueView, orangeErrorView, letsGetStartedView, welcomeBckView, passwordMasterLayout, orangePwdErrorView;
    TextView welcomeText,errorTextView, letsGetStartedTextView, welcomeBckTxtView, errorPwdMsg;

//Password Error Handling

```
    orangePwdErrorView = v.findViewById(R.id.orangePasswordErrorView);
    errorPwdMsg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.errorPasswordMessage);
```

//Layout code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="76.4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="23.6">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

sample_content_fragment framelayout takes the below code

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/grey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#58595B" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/orange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F26724"
        android:visibility="invisible" />



    <View
        android:id="@+id/yellow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FDB518"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#1893D2"
        android:visibility="invisible" />






    <TextView
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:id="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/clinicloud_logo"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/clinicloud_icon"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/orangeErrorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F26724"
        android:visibility="invisible" />





    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:text="@string/enter_email"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/errorMessage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <!--UI components for welcome back page-->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/welcomeBackView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#134F9F"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome_back"
        android:id="@+id/welcomeBackTxtView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/clinicloud_logo"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Password"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="#d2d1d1"
        />


    <!--UI components for Let's get started page-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/letsGetStartedView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#5C3A91"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Let&apos;s get started"
        android:id="@+id/letsGetStartedTxtView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/clinicloud_logo"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <!--Linear layout to show the create and confirm password--> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/passwordMasterView"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/createPwd"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="#F4F4F4"
            android:text="@string/create_password"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/confirmPwd"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="#E3E3E3"
            android:text="@string/confirm_password" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- To show password errors-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/orangePasswordErrorView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F26724"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/errorPasswordMessage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcomeTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <!-- To show password errors-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

The java logic is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523599/sliding-up-and-down-android

Please direct for any incorrect codings

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

> I kept the view invisible and when required I made it visible and wrote the code to slide up.

I think you must do it in DialogFragment or custom AlertDialog that will be shown above your layout, if dont want to do this try envelop your RelativeLayout in FrameLayout and adding in it LinearLayout for example but visout your code difficult to say in what problem it is

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a library for the sliding panel, one that I've had excellent experiences with (and supports the functionality that your after) is umano's AndroidSlidingUpPanel. https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel